# What is difference between libaugeas-ruby and libaugeas-ruby1.8 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, augeas

What is difference between libaugeas-ruby and libaugeas-ruby1.8 in Ubuntu?

I found that when I upgrade libaugeas-ruby, it doesn't upgrade  libaugeas-ruby1.8.

I can't see any different for this, very confusing

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libaugeas-ruby

http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libaugeas-ruby1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libaugeas-ruby is just a meta package which pulls either libaugeas-ruby1.8 or libaugeas-ruby1.9 depending on your Debian/Ubuntu version. The package doesn't actually contain anything.

Comment: however, in that link, the dependences only are libaugeas-ruby1.8, but not libaguease-ruby1.9? why? what is it use for such kind of design?

Comment: It is a very common design in Debian/Ubuntu. The goal is that you just install `libaugeas-ruby` and get the version that fits the default ruby version for your system (1.8 in your case). If you want the 1.9 version, you can install it manually. Whenever you upgrade the OS and 1.9 becomes the default version, the new `libaugeas-ruby` package will pull `libaugeas-ruby1.9` so you don't have to do it yourself. The kernel packages actually work the same way by the way.

Comment: from the link http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libaugeas-ruby, the link is only for ruby1.8, how can i point to 1.9? One of the thing i notice is that if the libaugeas-ruby has upgraded, the libaugeas-ruby1.8 doesn't get upgrade automatically ...

Comment: Squeeze still uses 1.8 as default. See in wheezy: http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libaugeas-ruby

Comment: As far upgrades, indeed, but that's not the point of the meta-package. If you use `apt-get upgrade` (or even `dist-upgrade`), all the packages will get upgraded.

Comment: sorry it is for update, not upgrade. I try to make a backport list for lucid, run apt-get install libagueas-ruby, the metapackage is updated! but as for libaugeas-ruby1.8 , it doesn't!!

Comment: Does this answer your question eventually?